# Dbus glib interface design and usage

Tags: c, object, dbus

In our project we use dbus for Inter Process communication. We have one interface where all the methods that need to be exposed to other process are tied together. That is only one interface for all the methods . Is it good idea ? Is it better to group the methods in to different interface ? We have around 50 methods. I am not familiar with Object oriented languages. But I feel it is better to group them in to different interfaces.

What will be the advantage of splitting the methods under different interfaces ? I need some justification for grouping methods under different interfaces.

Note that dbus has auto code generator which generates the necessary class and methods when xml is given as input.

Answer (score 1):

From a object-oriented perspective it's better to group messages in different interfaces according to their meaning. For a instant messaging software like pidgin you could have:

- **MyIPCInterface**:

  - accountCreate(...)
  - accountList(...)
  - accountRemove(...)
  - messageSend(...)
  - messageReceived(...) * signal
  - statusChange(....)
  - statusChanged(...) * signal

but a better choice would be to separate this into different interfaces according to their meaning:

- **AccountManagerInterface**

  - create(...)
  - list(...)
  - remove(...)
- **AccountInterface**

  - sendMessage(...)
  - messageReceived(...) * signal
  - statusChange(...)
  - statusChanged(...) * signal

Of course, there are many other ways to design this but the main point is that when you receive the "messageReceived" signal for an AccountInterface object, you know what account "object" received the signal, better than that you are separating the concerns of who should manage accounts from who should manage the account objects.

There's much more to say about that but I hope this may help to clarify...